# change attributes value using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

USing jquery how to chnage the attributes ng-click and `Create to Update` of the following html

```
<a class="btn pull-right btn-link" ng-click="create()" ng-class="{'btn-link-disabled':isSaveAndContinue,'btn-link':!isSaveAndContinue}">Create</a>

$(".btn .pull-right .btn-link").attr()
```

The final output should be

```
<a class="btn pull-right btn-link" ng-click="update()" ng-class="{'btn-link-   disabled':isSaveAndContinue,'btn-link':!isSaveAndContinue}">Update</a>
```

Comment: In jquery, `$(".btn .pull-right .btn-link").attr('ng-click','update()') `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do something like this with JQuery?

A simple approach would be to create something like this:

```
$scope.handleClick = function(){
   if(inUpdateMode){
      update();
   }
   else{
      create();
   }
}

$scope.getTitle = function(){
    return inUpdateMode ? "update" : "create";
}

<a class="btn pull-right btn-link" ng-click="handleClick()" ng-class="{'btn-link-disabled':isSaveAndContinue,'btn-link':!isSaveAndContinue}">{{getTitle()}}</a>
```

Another approach would be by creating a directive for this `<a>`.
A third approach would be using `ng-if` or `ng-show`:

```
<a class="btn pull-right btn-link" ng-if="!inUpdateMode" ng-click="create(param)" ng-class="{'btn-link-disabled':isSaveAndContinue,'btn-link':!isSaveAndContinue}">create</a>

<a class="btn pull-right btn-link" ng-if="inUpdateMode" ng-click="update()" ng-class="{'btn-link-disabled':isSaveAndContinue,'btn-link':!isSaveAndContinue}">update</a>
```

Comment: I think getTitle() should be inside ng-click. Otherwise it would call immediately without needing to click

Comment: what if i have to pass a parameter to create method only in this case

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - It's ok to get called without a click since you want to update the title. This will happen on each digest call (that's the only "problem" here).

Comment: @Rajeev - This can be done by passing a param to the handleClick method and passing it only to the create method - But if update and create have different prototypes I'd go with an ng-if\ng-show approach (e.g. create both <a> elements and add the ng-if or ng-show directive to them with a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".btn.pull-right.btn-link") // you don't need the spaces in the selector
    .attr('ng-click','update()') // change the ng-click attribube
    .text('Update'); // change the text inside
```

Comment: Why not just use AngularJS for this?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The OP clearly tagged jQuery. What the hell has angular to do with anything in this question??

Comment: Just because a question is tagged with something, doesn't mean OP is approaching the problem in the correct way. `ng-click` on the `a` element implies that AngularJS is being used. One solution could be to use AngularJS's `ng-show` and `ng-hide` attributes which can be used to show and hide content: Rather than dynamically updating the `ng-click` attribute, a more logical approach would be to define two separate `a` elements - one which has `update()` and another with `create()`, then using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` ensure that only the relevant one is ever visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn.pull-right.btn-link").attr('ng-click', 'update()').text('Update');
```

[here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/19gqw6ku/)